# How do I add attributes from an observable object to an array using Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a service call that returns a collection of FirebaseListObservable objects. I am trying to add a specific attribute (userName) from each into a regular javascript array like this:

```
  getUsernames(): string[] {
var userNameArray = [];
this.userList = this.service.getUsers();
this.userList.subscribe(
  users => {
    users.map(user =>
      //console.log(user.userName)
      userNameArray.push(user.userName)
    )
  }
);
console.log(userNameArray[0]);
return userNameArray;
```

}

This line

```
console.log(userNameArray[0]);
```

prints "undefined". Is that because of the asynchronous nature of the subscribe method? If so, how do I overcome this? If not, why aren't the values getting added to the array?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

For clarity, here is the code for the service that pulls the data from Firebase:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @Injectable()
    export class TwitchDatabaseService {
      userNames: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
      constructor(private af: AngularFire) { 
        this.userNames = af.database.list('/userNames');
      }


      getUsers(): FirebaseListObservable<any[]> {
        return this.userNames;
      }
```

Comment: Yes, that's because the observable is asynchronous and the `subscribe` callback hasn't been called yet.

Comment: Is that because of the asynchronous nature of the subscribe method? --> Of course it is

Comment: Is there a way that I can ensure the subscribe has finished before returning my array?

Comment: @dpberry178 that will still be an async operation. If you want to use the response from `userList` you need to do it inside the callback which is the `subscribe` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this :

```
this.service.getUsers().subscribe(
  users => return users.map(user => user.userName)
);
```

Comment: I was not able to get this to work either. I think I am fundamentally approaching this problem incorrectly, but being new to Angular2 I am not sure the best way to solve this.